# Access is denied returned when calling /me/messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am currently trying to make REST calls to get mailbox message stats for a particular account (i.e. read/unread count). I have done this in the Microsoft Graph Explorer and have managed to get the relevant `User.Read` and many other non-admin permissions.

When I try to replicate this process in Postman, I get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.". I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started) right until [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started#calling-the-mail-api) where I can't move forward despite the correct permissions.

Even my token generation response contains the `"scope": "User.Read"`

I just want to make a call to `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`
The registered app is the account of the email I am trying to monitor. I can make this call successfully Graph Explorer, but I am unable to replicate the results with Postman, PowerShell, or groovy

Comment: There isn't enough information here to go on. Please show how you're obtaining your token, how you're calling the API and the bearer token your sending with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out Delegated Permissions weren't enough, despite the fact that it was what I understood my circumstance.
It only started working after I gave it APP Permissions

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. You stated you were getting the error when calling `/me/messages` but `me` _isn't supported_ by App Only scopes. Something was misconfigured, but it wasn't the lack of App permissions.

Answer (score 0):

To make a request to read the signed-in user's mail (`GET .../me/messages`), your application needs the delegated permissions (i.e. scope) `Mail.Read`. Just having `User.Read` is not sufficient. This is also described in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0